# How to delete a record by the secondary key for tarantool using java client?

Tags: java, tarantool

Java client sources

Function select has index:

```
public java.util.List select(int space, int index, java.lang.Object key, int offset, int limit, int iterator)
```

But replace, update and delete given only space & key:

```
public java.util.List delete(int space, java.lang.Object key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete is performed on a primary key, so it's an atomic operation because primary key enforces uniqueness. A secondary index might be unique, but it might be not as well, therefore you would need to start a transaction to ensure atomicity in a non-unique secondary index key. So that's a reason why there is no delete/update/insert on a secondary index for Java yet. It's a good question if tarantool allows transactions started remotely, but I doubt it'd be useful.

So you would need to do the following to get it working:

1. write a stored procedure in Lua to iterate over your index/select the value you need
2. put the procedure you wrote into your Tarantool instances
3. call it from your Java code by name, by using a `public List call(String var1, Object... var2);`

E.g.

```
    -- Lua function
    function deleteFromSpaceByUniqueSecondaryIndex(secondaryId)
        box.space.YourSpace.index.yourSecondaryIdx:delete(secondaryId)
    end
```

.....

```
    //call it from Java like that
    tarantoolConn.call("deleteFromSpaceByUniqueSecondaryIndex", secondaryId);
```